# How to stop Git from treating vendor git repo as git submodule?

Tags: git

I use composer to manage lots of dependencies , some of them are git repos , I also use git submodule to manage some of git repositories in our own git server .

when I try to execute

```
git submodule update
```

Git will complain that all vendor dependencies  are not submodules.
the error message looks like this.

> No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path
>   'vendor/a2lix/translation-form-bundle/A2lix/TranslationFormBundle'

all these vendor dependencies are managed by composer, so they are definitely not git submodule , anyway to get rid of this trouble?

Answer (score 0):

If no vendor submodules are declared in the `.gitmodules`, but git is complaining about submodule paths, that means the `.git` folder includes submodule metadata (which are not in sync with the `.gitmodules` content)

Simply try and remove `.git/modules/vendor/a2lix/translation-form-bundle/A2lix/TranslationFormBundle` to see if that specific error message disappear.

Comment: thanks, I list the directory  .git/modules/ , there is no vendor  dir in that directory.

Comment: @VidyVideni And do you have a path including "vendor" in the .gitmodules file?